# How to find necessary access web token for IBM Watson`s speech-to-text service web-socket endpoint?

Tags: python, audio, websocket, streaming, ibm-watson

I am new in working with IBM Watson`s services. I want to test the speech-to-text service. I have created the new STT service and assign it to the created app. According to the [docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text/websockets.html#section-WSopen)  if I want to use STT web-socket endpoint it requires web-token for authentication. I found different articles on how to receive IBM tokens. The [first](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-iam.html#iam) says, that I need to create it from my API key but when I use that token I do not pass auth. Another way is to receive a token as was suggested [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/206904/watson-token-for-stt-websockets/#answer-206922) but for that, I need username and pass. [Docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-credentials.html#creating-credentials#getting-credentials-manually) say that I can find them in service credentials. But I have no such fields in service credentials JSON.

My service credentials looks next:

```
{
  "apikey": "my_api_key",
  "iam_apikey_description": "description",
  "iam_apikey_name": "key_name",
  "iam_role_crn": "my_role_crn",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "my_serviceid_crn",
  "url": "my_url_endpoint"
}
```

Please help me to figure out how to receive an access token for my STT service with api_key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can access IBM Watson service APIs by using the API keys that were
>   generated for the service instance. You use the API key to generate an
>   IAM access token. You also use this process if you are developing an
>   application that needs to work with other IBM Cloud services

So, you need to do a POST request `identity/token` method to generate an IAM access token by passing an API key. One example with cURL:

```
curl -k -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/json" --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" --data-urlencode "apikey={your apikey}" "https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token"
```

And the response will be something like:

```
 "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUz......sgrKIi8hdFs",
 "refresh_token": "SPrXw5tBE3......KBQ+luWQVY",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "expiration": 1473188353
```

One example calling Watson Services:

```
curl -X GET \
--header "Authorization: Bearer {token}" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments?version=2017-11-07"
```

Obs.: I do suggest you use the Python SDK. The SDKs accept an API key and manage the lifecycle of the tokens, take a look in **[this example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/speech_to_text_v1.py#L9)**, you just need to pass your token.

- See more about Authentication IAM using Watson services [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-iam.html#iamtoken).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is what I was looking for.